# Insert and fetch data coordinate canvas HTML5 Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, canvas

I want to insert coordinate X,Y from my canvas HTML5 into the database (MYSQL using PHP CODEIGNITER) and then I fetch all data to my canvas as a graph 2D. As far I know the 0 point from canvas at top left corner, then I set the 0 point to the bottom left corner. I can insert all coordinate into my table but when I fetch data all coordinates from the table I cannot get correct position.  Please help me to fix my problem to set 0 point when I insert data and when I fetch all data..

Here is my code HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="780" height="780" style="border:1px solid #000; ">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Here in my code for PHP inside Javascript when I retrieve data from DB:

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var HEIGHT = c.height;
ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(0, HEIGHT);
ctx.scale(1, -1);
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
    <?php
        foreach($trial as $t){
            $x_ori=$t->x;
            $y_ori=$t->y;
            echo "ctx.lineTo(".$x_ori.", ".$y_ori.");";
        }
    ?>
ctx.stroke();
ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
ctx.beginPath();
</script>
```

Here is my insert code using AJAX:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
}
$(function(){
    $("#myCanvas").click(function(event){
        var x = new Number();
        var y = new Number();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

        if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
        {
            x = event.x;
            y = event.y;
        }
        else 
        {
            x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
            document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        }

        x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
        y -= canvas.offsetTop;          
        var coor=cartToScreen(x,y);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controllers/insert",
            method: "POST",
            data: {x:x,y:y},
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data)
            {                                       
                $("#xx").load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>page/refresh");                     
            }
        });

    });
});
```

[Here is my graph 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI8Y8.jpg)

Thankyou